# <f:convertNumber> inside <h:outputText> doesn't work

Tags: jsf

I want to do output text with value of currency:

```
<h:form rendered="#{not empty cartBean.cartMap}">
    <h:outputText escape="false" styleClass="cart-text"
              value="Your shopping cart: &lt;b&gt;
                    #{cartBean.cartDishesCount}&lt;/b&gt; items, 
                    total= &lt;b&gt;#{cartBean.updateTotalPrice()}&lt;/b&gt;">
        <f:convertNumber currencyCode="USD" type="currency"/> <!-- doesn't work -->
    </h:outputText>
</h:form>
```

but `<f:converNumber>` is ignoring and page output still looks like this:

> Your shopping cart: 9 items, total= 46.800000000000004

Comment: How should the renderer know which parts of your String he should format into a currency?

Comment: You've another major problem: using floating point types instead of `BigDecimal` for money and prices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to have only the value in the value as in

```
<h:outputText value="#{cartBean.updateTotalPrice}" >
  <f:convertNumber currencyCode="USD" type="currency" />
</h:outputText>
```

The convert number expects a number, since the value of the outputText is a string, it does not recognize it.

Anything that is not the number would be displayed separately.

If you want to explicitly specify the location then this is an option

```
<f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" locale="en_US" />
```

Comment: sure, when i split my output in two parts, which second one is only the value  of `cartBean.updateTotalPrice` it begins to work as I need. In this case `currencyCode="USD" ` is working as well. Thank you a lot!